# where to sanatize data client side or server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, twitter

i am making a social networking site and have come across a problem.... for example- when a user posts something or comments on a status then where should i sanatize the data like seperating the `tagged friends` and `hastags` etc... I am probably more confused after coming across `twitters [(twitter-text-js)][1]`... as it sanatizes the contents client side and then sends it to the backend... 
It would be great it some of you can shed some light on it.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not both? I would say backend is an absolute must, though.

Comment: You should include client-side validation of user input, but since many of these methods can be circumvented you should always sanitize user input on the backend.

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js It doesn't appear twitter-text-js is used much for sanitization.

Comment: if strangers will be using the system, you need to use server-side sanitation.

Answer (score 2):

Data sanitation must happen on server side. Everything you do on client side can be bypassed (For example if you do it with javascript -> an Attacker just disables javascript.)

For usability reasons you can **additionally** implement it on the client side.

Comment: then why does twitter use this text-js for

Comment: fewer replacements on the server makes for a lighter processing load, why not make 99.99% of legit customers do that for for them for free? When you have that much traffic, little stuff like that adds up into more savings than many sites consume. it also allows live previews and  stuff like that if you know how the tweet will come out...

Comment: That is not true. modern webapps will simply **not work** with javascript disabled (facebook, gmail, and countless others) so, while I agree the sanitation should happen on the server-side, it is still worth while to have a fail-safe solution on the client as well, doesn't do no harm.

Answer (score 1):

Always validate and sanitize data server-side even if you do so on the client-side. It's also important to sanitize data using something like htmlentities() and/or htmlspecialchars() when displaying data from the database.

Learn to use PDO prepared statements for inserting data into your database as you will not need to worry about sanitizing the data before hand.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/